Unexpected logout
My Ubuntu version is Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS. Although I've been using it without any problems so far, it's suddenly happened that my administrator account is immediately logouted whenever I login. Actually, after login my admin account, it suddenly leaves the session and shows login menu. Just to be sure, I restart my PC and login again. But the same things happen. Meanwhile, non-administrator account has no such problem. How can I fix this problem. Thanks in advance.

Is this when logging in via the GUI greeter, or via a CLI? Please [edit] your question to include the flavor and version of Ubuntu that you are using as well.

Ubuntu has, for several releases, disabled the root account, due to security reasons. Is that what you mean by "my admin account"? Use sudo and sudoedit, after reading man sudo sudoers.

Is it a real, deliberate logout? Or is it actually a crash? (Crashes usually leave a file behind in /var/crash)
